# How to publish multiples reports with same dataset?

Tags: powerbi, dataset, report, workspace, directquery

I'm trying to have multiples reports with same dataset in a single workspace with Power BI.
I know I have to use "Power BI dataset" in Power BI Desktop.
But every time I publish, it creates a direct query new dataset instead of use the previous one.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Power BI Service, you can click on the ellipsis of the dataset and **Create report**.
[image]